# What is the true meaning of the returned value of `delete`?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

According to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), the `delete` keyword

> Returns false only if the property exists and cannot be deleted. It
>   returns true in all other cases.

However, I see cases where `delete` returns `true`, despite the property not being deleted:

```
delete Window
delete alert
delete dir
delete console
delete 2
delete null
delete {}.x
...
```

In fact, almost all properties of `window` return true with `delete`, as can be seen by the running the following script in `about:blank`:

```
for(a in window) { if(delete window[a]) { console.log(a); } }
```

However, most properties of `window` do not actually get deleted. What is the true meaning of the returned value of `delete`? Why does it return `true` for properties it doesn't delete?

(Note: I would be interested in references to Chromium code explaining the behaviour of `delete`.)

Comment: That line outputted quite a few names for me, and then disabled jQuery so I couldn't say so. It seems to be working as intended.

Comment: Have you tried the examples like `delete Window`, etc. ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The window is a [host object](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.8), one whose semantics are defined by the host environment, e.g. the browser.  `delete` when applied to properties of host objects is more complicated than when applied to native objects.

> Host objects may support these internal properties with any implementation-dependent behaviour as long as it is consistent with the specific host object restrictions stated in this document.

[Section 11.4.1 - The `delete` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.1) says

```
If IsUnresolvableReference(ref) then,
  If IsStrictReference(ref) is true, throw a SyntaxError exception.
  Else, return true.
```

so when a host object doesn't support deletion or modification of a property, then it returns an unresolvable reference or a reference which pretends to be deleted.  Either approach causes `true` to be returned in non-strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

The javascript implementation used by browsers has always been bending the rules. Part of the javascript DOM API is not even possible in pure javascript, for instance the dom innerHTML="something" that triggers an event. This was fixed in EcmaScript5, but you can't rely on the Browser Object Model being 100% legit javascript. AFAIK, as long as you don't put a foot into the DOM and the BOM, you can rely completly on the ecmascript standard.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are acting on low level objects in your program, the attributes may in fact be being deleted and then immediately re-added, though I have no idea how you could test for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

On that MDN page, it specifies the syntax, which does not include `delete object` as your first set of examples uses. It does specify the syntax `delete object[property]` as your second example shows. However, what happens with DOM (host) objects is not specified. See [this article for more information](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#delete_and_host_objects).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the browsers are protecting the runtime environment of the browser, in your test.

Once upon a time, that might not have been the case, but as far as tests go, this is akin to asking why Windows doesn't allow you to open the command-shell and run:

```
> cd /
> deltree *.*
```

anymore.

Because there is really no good reason to be able to do such a thing, when you're expecting the environment to actually continue to run, afterwards, and not take down your whole browser, plus potentially the instance of your OS you're currently running, or whatever other fun errors could occur when you basically ask a program to erase itself in real-time, while it currently has low-level access to your GPU/soundcard/input devices.

Delete will return failure in the case where you try to delete a var.  In terms of global properties the browser needs to function, most of them are defined like a property (ie: `window.location`) but are done so at a low-level (ie: you don't have access).  So theoretically, they're objects which can be deleted.  But they're protected, so you can't, but that's not going to change the return statement of `delete`, because that would alter `delete`'s expected behaviour.

So:

```
function () {
    var obj = { prop : true };
    delete obj; /* fail */
    delete object.prop; /* succeed */
}
```