# Return value of delete operator?

Tags: javascript

From the [MDN `delete` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

Return value:

> Throws in strict mode if the property is an own non-configurable
>   property (returns false in non-strict). Returns true in all other
>   cases.

There are some things I don't understand:

1. What is a non-configurable property?
2. when I run this code in chrome console it return true:

   ```
   var a={'b':'b'};
   delete a.b; //it return true
   ```

I think the Chrome console runs code in non-strict mode. If that is the case, then according to MDN it should returns `false`. Why does it return `true`?

3. According to MDN the `delete` operator returns true in all other cases. What are the other cases? I know one case (strict mode with a configurable property). Are there any other cases ?

Comment: The way I read that statement, is that it will throw and exception in strict mode and return false if it can't delete it in non-strict.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the true meaning of the returned value of \`delete\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145901/what-is-the-true-meaning-of-the-returned-value-of-delete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [A property that](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1) you cannot delete, change to be an accessor property, or change the attributes (other than [[Value]]) of.
2. You're misreading the precedence. In strict mode it throws if the property is non-configurable. In non-strict mode it returns false if the property is non-configurable. Otherwise it returns true.
3. When the property is configurable.

Answer (score 1):

To know delete operator in detail, You probably should look into this amazing blog by kangax: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

which describes well about [dontdelete] attribute, which in-tern comes as an essential attribute while trying to delete a variable or property.